# Deploy Sinatra template on Helicon Zoo

Tags: ruby, iis, sinatra

1. I installed the Ruby Hosting Package and Sinatra on Windows Server 2008R2 with IIS using [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/).
2. I downloaded and imported the Sinatra template from [Helicon Zoo Templates](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/templates.htm) using web deploy on IIS

Now I get this error when navigating to the website:

```
[tid-7800168] paths need to start with / (ArgumentError)
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:30:in `block in remap'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:22:in `each'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:22:in `map'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:22:in `remap'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:18:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:142:in `new'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:142:in `generate_map'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:128:in `to_app'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:45:in `build_app'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:16:in `initialize'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `new'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `initialize'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `new'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `<module:Zack>'
C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade Helicon Zoo Module from the feed to the version 1.0.0.47. Just go to Zoo -> Modules and install it again.

Answer (score 1):

Neil,

I posted a similar question just a couple of days ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595286/paths-need-to-start-with-argumenterror).
As you can see from Yaroslav's reply, an updated version of Helicon Zoo module may help your case. 
I think it is something to do with IIS Express installation in my case (I couldn't install it successfully through the web platform installer and had to go directly to download it from the MS site + when I run the ruby web server it works). I don't think my issue will help you, but maybe the Helicon update might?