# paths need to start with / (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webmatrix, helicontech

This question is similar to that of [Neil Hoff's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569614/deploy-sinatra-template-on-helicon-zoo) from a few days ago.
I downloaded Ruby On Rails using Helicon Zoo's ruby package. I am running this on Windows 7 using IIS Express & WebMatrix.

Like, the other question when I browse to the site, I am getting the following:

```
[tid-12570000] paths need to start with / (ArgumentError)
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:33:in `block in remap'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:25:in `map'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:25:in `remap'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:18:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:128:in `new'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:128:in `to_app'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:45:in `build_app'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:16:in `initialize'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `new'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `initialize'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `new'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `<module:Zack>'
C:/ZooExpress/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I know that RoR on Windows does not have a big following, but have searched for the past 2 days for a solution to this, and via google, the only remotely related text seems to be the other SO question referred to above without an answer. 
Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your bug come from rack. I think he search a url like this : `http://localhost/`.  To know what he do, I suggest you to go in this file : `C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb` and change the code to see what's the value of `location`. You can try to debug your code with pry or ruby-debug. I know, it's difficult. I have no better answer for the moment. Gool luck!

Comment: Dougui, I did think of doing this, but as a newbie I am still figuring my way round how to debug at all, nevermind such internal code. I will give it a bash, and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade Helicon Zoo Module from the feed to the version 1.0.0.47 or higher. Just go to Zoo -> Modules and install it again.

Comment: Yaroslav thanks for the reply - much appreciated. What is Helicon Zoo's part in all this?  I understand that I must have it when following (what I presume to be) [your article](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/324014/ruby-on-rails-on-windows-in-production), but I had problems with my IIS installation through web platform installer, so I installed it separately via the MS site, and then re-attempted the Helicon Zoo install.  Would that cause a problem?  I def think it's related because I can get the app running using the rails server.

Comment: It is hard to tell remotely what have been installed. Since you are getting some response from Ruby, then I guess Helicon Zoo Module is installed. What kind of problems have you experienced with Web Platform Installer? Can you run it again to upgrade Helicon Zoo Module. The problem you describing is a known issue with one specific build of Helicon Zoo that has been fixed recently.

Comment: Yaroslav, when I attempt to install the Helicon Zoo module, it then looks for 19 IIS components (including IIS itself) so the installation fails.  Can you explain the role of Helicon Zoo on the whole picture?  Is it a go-between for Ruby & Windows? As far as I can make out since I am running the rails server, it is going nowhere near IIS, hence why its working

Comment: Helicon Zoo Module is a connector between (in your situation) Ruby and IIS. I guess you are getting confused because you are using IIS Express instead of IIS. In this situation you need to go to Web Platform Installer settings and select IIS Express as a target platform, then install Helicon Zoo Module for IIS Express. This should fix your current issue.